# Alignment of array with 0 elements

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, allocator

C++ [allows dynamic allocation of zero-sized arrays](https://herbsutter.com/2009/09/02/when-is-a-zero-length-array-okay/):

```
int* p = new int[0];
delete[] p;
```

I can't do much with such a pointer (as the array has no elements), but the new expression is required to give me back a valid (`!= nullptr`) pointer which I then have to `delete[]` again as if it was an actual array.

Are there any requirements regarding the alignment of the memory returned by such a new expression? Consider:

```
struct alignas(8) Foo {
    int x;
};

Foo* p = new Foo[0];
delete[] p;
```

Is `p` guaranteed to point to an 8-aligned address? Furthermore, if I write a custom allocator, am I required to return pointers to aligned addresses in such a case?

Comment: As dereferencing the pointer is UB does it matter?

Comment: @RichardCritten I honestly don't know. That's part of why I'm asking.

Answer (score 8):

basic.stc.dynamic.allocation/2 of N3337 (basically C++11):

> The allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of
>   storage. If it is successful, it shall return the address of the start
>   of a block of storage whose length in bytes shall be at least as large
>   as the requested size. There are no constraints on the contents of the
>   allocated storage on return from the allocation function. The order,
>   contiguity, and initial value of storage allocated by successive calls
>   to an allocation function are unspeciﬁed. **The pointer returned shall
>   be suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer of any
>   complete object type with a fundamental alignment requirement** (3.11)
>   and then used to access the object or array in the storage allocated
>   (until the storage is explicitly deallocated by a call to a
>   corresponding deallocation function). Even if the size of the space
>   requested is zero, the request can fail. If the request succeeds, the
>   value returned shall be a non-null pointer value (4.10) p0 diﬀerent
>   from any previously returned value p1, unless that value p1 was
>   subsequently passed to an operator delete. The eﬀect of dereferencing
>   a pointer returned as a request for zero size is undeﬁned.

Fundamental alignment (basic.align/2):

> A fundamental alignment is represented by an alignment less than or
>   equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in
>   all contexts, which is equal to alignof(std::max_align_t)

Extended alignment (basic.align/3):

> An extended alignment is represented by an alignment greater than
>   alignof(std::max_align_t).
>
> It is implementation-deﬁned whether any extended alignments are
>   supported and the contexts in which they are supported

So, the returned pointer by `operator new` must have fundamental alignment. Even if zero size specified. And it is implementation defined, whether 8 is fundamental or extended alignment. If it is fundamental, then `Foo` is OK. If it is extended, then it is implementation defined that `Foo` is supported with `operator new`.

Note, that for C++17, the situation is improved:

---

[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation/2 of C++17](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic#allocation-2):

> The allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of
>   storage. If it is successful, it shall return the address of the start
>   of a block of storage whose length in bytes shall be at least as large
>   as the requested size. There are no constraints on the contents of the
>   allocated storage on return from the allocation function. The order,
>   contiguity, and initial value of storage allocated by successive calls
>   to an allocation function are unspecified. **The pointer returned shall
>   be suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer to any
>   suitable complete object type** ([new.delete.single]) and then used to
>   access the object or array in the storage allocated (until the storage
>   is explicitly deallocated by a call to a corresponding deallocation
>   function). Even if the size of the space requested is zero, the
>   request can fail. If the request succeeds, the value returned shall be
>   a non-null pointer value ([conv.ptr]) p0 different from any previously
>   returned value p1, unless that value p1 was subsequently passed to an
>   operator delete. Furthermore, for the library allocation functions in
>   [new.delete.single] and [new.delete.array], p0 shall represent the
>   address of a block of storage disjoint from the storage for any other
>   object accessible to the caller. The effect of indirecting through a
>   pointer returned as a request for zero size is undefined.

I've put emphasis on the relevant part. That sentence means that the returned pointer of `void *operator new(...)` should have suitable alignment. It doesn't mention zero size as a special case (but, of course, it is UB to dereference the returned pointer).

So the answer is the usual, there is no special handling of zero:

1. `void *operator new(std::size_t)` must return an aligned pointer of `alignof(std​::​max_­align_­t)`
2. `void *operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t align)` must return an aligned pointer of `align`)

Note that it is implementation defined, which version will be called for `Foo`. It depends on whether 8 is equal or less than `alignof(std​::​max_­align_­t)`. If it is less, then the 1st version is called (because it doesn't have *extended alignment*). Otherwise the 2nd is called.

---

UPDATE: As Massimiliano Janes comments, these paragraphs apply to the result of `operator new`, not to the result of new expression. An implementation could add an arbitrary offset to the result of `operator new[]`. And the standard is silent about the value of this `x` offset:

> new T[5] results in one of the following calls:
>
> operator new[](sizeof(T) * 5 + x)
>
> operator new[](sizeof(T) * 5 + x, std::align_val_t(alignof(T)))
>
> Here, each instance of x is a non-negative unspecified value
>   representing array allocation overhead; the result of the
>   new-expression will be offset by this amount from the value returned
>   by operator new[]. This overhead may be applied in all array
>   new-expressions, including those referencing the library function
>   operator new[](std​::​size_­t, void*) and other placement allocation
>   functions. The amount of overhead may vary from one invocation of new
>   to another.

However, in my opinion, this `x` offset cannot be arbitrary. If it is not a multiple of alignment, then the new expression would return a non-aligned pointer (in all cases. Not just the zero, but the non-zero size parameter as well). That's clearly not we want.

So I think this is a hole in the standard. Value of `x` should be constrained to be a multiple of alignment (at least in the non-zero allocation case). But because of this omission, it seems that the standard doesn't guarantee that a `new[]` expression returns an aligned pointer at all (in the non-zero case as well).

Comment: sadly, this does not answer the question either; first, the result of the new expression may be arbitrarily offset from the allocation result in the array case (see [[expr.new#15](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#15)]) so it does not prove that the result of the *new expression* is aligned for the zero-sized array case.

Comment: Second, it's not clear if a non-aligned pointer used to represent an empty array is "suitably aligned  so that it can be converted to a pointer..." or not ... the only thing we know (from [[basic.compound#3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3)]) is that a non-aligned pointer is an *invalid pointer value*, but nowhere is said that delete[] requires a valid pointer value, it's just said that it needs the result of a previous new[]...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: For your first concern: why zero-sized arrays special here? Second: if invalid pointer value was allowed, then that sentence wouldn't make any sense. I think that "can be converted" means that it won't end up in an invalid value.

Comment: `void* operator new[](std::size_t size)` only needs to return a pointer that is "suitably aligned to represent any array object of that size or smaller".

Comment: "why zero-sized arrays special here?" in the non-zero case it's required to point the the first array element (so, if the allocation for the alignement of T is supported, the pointer must be aligned), whereas in the zero case we only know that the result of the expression *"new T[0]"* is "new[](x) + offset x" where x is an *unspecified* non negative number.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: it seems that you have a valid point on this one. However, something is strange to me. That `x` offset should be a multiple of alignment, shouldn't it (in the general case)? If it is not, then the new expression would return a pointer with bad alignment. But of course, an implementation could choose that `x` can be anything for the 0-size case. I'll edit my answer a little bit, thanks for the info!

Comment: I think the whole issue boils down to the question: should the new expression and the allocation functions required to *always* result in a *valid* pointer value (even in the zero array case) ? if yes, [basic.compound#3] applies and non-null valid pointers must be always aligned (indipendently of the object they point to, if any). As you, I'm inclined on the positive in both cases, but I don't know ... :)